# HtmlWebpackPlugin order of included bundle files

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

My environment is as follows

- webpack
- angular2
- HtmlWebpackPlugin

my extracted webpack.config.js file is as follows

```
entry: {
  'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
  'main': './src/main.browser.ts'
},

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html'
  }),
```

The final html that gets generated has the following scripts references

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
```

My problem is that polyfills.bundle.js is referenced after main.bundle.js.  Due to this the app does not work.  From what I know the script files should be referenced in the reverse order.  How do I fix this?  Plus how does HtmlWebpackPlugin determine the order in which to insert the scripts?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `'manual'` value for [`chunksSortMode`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration) option and plugin will sort your chunks as they ordered in `chunks` option.
See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/481#issuecomment-300180648) for details.

Example:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  ...
  chunks: ['polyfills', 'main'],
  chunksSortMode: 'manual'
})
```